# mindate in jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jQuery datepick . what I want to do is I want to set the mindate for 'from' option based upon the date selected in the 'to option'. I tried something like this but did not worked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var date='#gp_vdate_from';
$('#gp_vdate_from, #gp_vdate_to').datepick({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy',minDate: date, showTrigger: '#calImg' });
});
```

It works naturally  but does not consider the mean date. I saw some answers in stackoverflow but none helped. Hope to get response. Don't mind if this is too easy for you as I am just learning to use jquery.

Comment: Try: `var date = new Date($('#gp_vdate_from').val());`

Comment: try the following link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875389/nothing-happen-on-setting-mindate-in-jquery-datepicker

Comment: Thanks But none is working. It disables the date selection itself

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$('#gp_vdate_from, #gp_vdate_to').datepick({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy',minDate: new Date(date), showTrigger: '#calImg' });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help But It disables the selection of the date. not able to select the date after doing this.